# Anyone can help me with the path module from node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have this folder structure:

```
/home
    /src
        app.js
    test.js
```

**app.js**

```
const path = require('path');       
                                    
module.exports = {                  
    path1: path.resolve(),          
    path2: () => path.resolve()     
}
```

**test.js**

```
const test = require('./src/app');      
                                    
console.log('#1', test.path1)    
console.log('#2', test.path2())
```

- Now if I run this command, I get this results:

```
drive:\home > node test.js
> #1 drive:\home
> #2 drive:\home
```

- I was wondering why I don't get these results instead:

```
drive:\home > node test.js
> #1 drive:\home\src
> #2 drive:\home
```

Comment: `path.resolve()` resolves to the current working directory. It's unrelated to the location of the file. _"If, after processing all given path segments, an absolute path has not yet been generated, the current working directory is used."_ [`path.resolve([...paths])`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Answer (score 0):

`path.resolve()` resolves to the current working directory. It's unrelated to the location of the file. *"If, after processing all given path segments, an absolute path has not yet been generated, the current working directory is used."* [`path.resolve([...paths])`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

Comment: Hi! Do you mean the directory where package.json is? Is that my working directory?

Comment: @JR_PT No, the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is the directory where the process is started. When you type `node test.js` into your terminal it's the current path. It's completely unrelated to your project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

when you heed this result

```
drive:\home > node test.js
> #1 drive:\home
> #2 drive:\home\src
```

app.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  path1: path.resolve(),
  path2: ()=>path.resolve("app"),
};
```

basically you need file name
when you use `path.resolve()`it get you current directory name as a paramter  by default